# App Crashes due to Db creation on every launch

Tags: android, sqlite, crash

I have an application in which i am trying to create a Database. On the first run the application works properly. Subsequent launch of the application it crashes. The error is because the application is trying to create the db again.

So i want to know how to create a database or tables only if they dont exists or only if the application is run the first time.

Comment: Are you sure its crashing because its trying to open the database again ? Try closing the database when you go out of the activity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can extend the class SQLiteOpenHelper to handle different versions of your database. Here is an example:

```
public class MyDbOpenHelper extends **SQLiteOpenHelper** {
    final static int VERSION = 2;

    public MyDbOpenHelper(Context context, String dbname) {
        super(context, dbname, null, VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void **onCreate**(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        /* TODO SQL-Queries for new Database */
    }

    @Override
    public void **onUpgrade**(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        /* SQL-Queries t*/
        if (oldVersion < 2) {
            db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE my_table ADD COLUMN new_attrubte INTEGER");
        }
    }
}
```

Handle of database is new in onCreate and if it exist, onUpgrade is called with existing version number in oldVersion parameter.

Comment: The `SQLiteOpenHelper` is the recommended way to go. Heres Googles recommendation http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db and their sample project http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/notepad/index.html that covers many things (one of them the database helper)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Just wondering now that how to run this MyDbOpenHelper.java file.. when i start the application and the first activity is Main.java

Answer (score 4):

[SQLite has](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html) a `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS` command. You could try that.

> It is usually an error to attempt to create a new table in a database that already contains a table, index or view of the same name. However, if the "IF NOT EXISTS" clause is specified as part of the CREATE TABLE statement and a table or view of the same name already exists, the CREATE TABLE command simply has no effect (and no error message is returned). An error is still returned if the table cannot be created because of an existing index, even if the "IF NOT EXISTS" clause is specified.